# How to deal with the text file with UTF-8 code imported in R to do LDA topic modeling

Tags: r, utf-8, lda, topic-modeling

I am a newbie in R.
I was trying to import a text file into R to do an LDA topic modeling analysis. The file is about movie tags and there are some strange characters inside, such as "ã¯â¼å". Then I search it online, these strange characters are UTF-8? Not sure if it is correct.
My question is how to deal with these characters, is there any way that can transform them into normal characters? Because when I need to do further analysis for the text material, it returns error "invalid multibyte string 129". (ã¯â¼å in line 129 in the text file)

Comment: Hi, I see this is your first question.  Please put the code and other items right in the question body (with formatting) instead of in images.  It's not clear to me why you are talking about UTF-8.

Comment: Hi Elin, sorry for the inconvenience, this is my first question. And I just started to learn R, not sure if I say it clearly. thanks for the comment.

Comment: when I used "fileEncoding="latin1", it works~